# I am trying to sorting data in django the data is coming from different table in different dropdown but I am stuck I am not getting perfect match

Tags: python, django

**basically I am making a search engine for car's selling company in this search engine data is coming from different models but I am not getting the accurate data using these filter how can I get the perfect match I need help to solve this problem I will be very thankfull to you **
[image]

**home.html**

```
   <form action="/searchdd" method="POST" id="indexForm" data-cars-url="{% url 
  'ajax_load_cars' 
     %}">
       {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
     
      <div class=" col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">Make</label>
        <select id="companyddl" name="companyname" class="searchengine">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--Select Make--</option>
          {% for company in companies %}
          <option value="{{company.CompanyID}}">{{company.CompanyName}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">Model</label>
        <select id="carddl" name="carname" class="searchengine">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--Select Model--</option>
                       
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">From Year</label>
        <select name="fromdate" id="fromdate">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
          {% for manf in manufac %}
          <option value="{{manf.ManufacturingYMID}}">{{manf.ManufacturingDate}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">To Year</label>
        <select name="todate" id="todate">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
          {% for manf in manufac %}
          <option value="{{manf.ManufacturingYMID}}">{{manf.ManufacturingDate}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
     
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row"> 

      <div class="dropdown my-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <label for="" class="white">Type </label>
        <select name="type" id="type" class="searchengine" style="padding-right: 7px; margin-left: 3px;">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--Select Type--</option>
          {% for ty in type %}
          <option value="{{ty.TypeID}}">{{ty.TypeName}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown my-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12"> 
        <label for="" class="white">Steering </label>          
        <select name="steering" id="steering" class="searchengine">
          <option value="">--Select Steering--</option>    
          {% for str in steer %}          
          <option value="{{str.SteeringID}}">{{str.SteeringName}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class=" col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">Search </label>
        <button name="search" href="{% url 'searchdd' %}?companyname={{company.CompanyID}}?carname={{carname.CarID}}?fromyear={{fromyear.ManufacturingYMID}}?toyear={{toyear.ManufacturingYMID}}?type={{type.TypeID}}?steering={{steering.SteeringID}}" class="btn-dark" type="submit" value="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Here&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
      </div>
              
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
 def searchdd(request):
companyname = request.POST.get('companyname', "")
carname = request.POST.get('carname', "")
fromdate = request.POST.get('fromdate', "")
todate = request.POST.get('todate', "")
type = request.POST.get('type', "")
steering = request.POST.get('steering', "")

if search:
    # searchresult = Car.objects.filter(Q(company__CompanyName__contains=companyname)|Q(CarName=carname)|Q(mdate__ManufacturingDate__contains=fromdate)|Q(mdate__ManufacturingDate__contains=todate)|Q(type__TypeName__contains=type)|Q(steering__SteeringName__contains=steering))
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(Q(company__CompanyName__contains=companyname)|Q(CarName=carname))
else:
    searchresult = Car.objects.all()

if companyname:
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(company__CompanyName=companyname)

if carname:
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(carname)

if fromdate:
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(mdate__ManufacturingDate=fromdate)

if todate:
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(mdate__ManufacturingDate=todate)

if type:
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(type__TypeName=type)

if steering:
    searchresult = Car.objects.filter(steering__SteeringName=steering)

context = {'searchresult':searchresult}
return render(request, 'app/searchdd.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    CarID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CarName = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Car Name")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name="Company Name", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default="")
    type = models.ForeignKey(CarType, verbose_name="Vehicle Type", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CarImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='productimg', verbose_name="Vehicle Image")
    RefNo = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Ref No", null=True, blank=True)
    ChassisNo = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Chassis No", null=True, 
    blank=True)
    ModelCode = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Model Code", null=True, 
    blank=True)
    EngineSize = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Engine Size", null=True, blank=True)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Location", null=True, blank=True)
    Version = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Version/Class", null=True, blank=True)
    Drive = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Drive", null=True, blank=True)
    Transmission = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Transmission", null=True, blank=True)
    mdate = models.ForeignKey(ManufacturingYM, verbose_name="Manufacturing Year", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    Mileage = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Mileage", null=True, blank=True)
    EngineCode = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Engine Code", null=True, blank=True)
    steering = models.ForeignKey(Steering, verbose_name="Steering", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")        
    ExtColor = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Ext Color", null=True, blank=True)
    Fuel = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Fuel", null=True, blank=True)
    Seats = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Seats", null=True, blank=True)
    Door = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Door", null=True, blank=True)
    M3 = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="M3", null=True, blank=True)
    Dimensions = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Dimensions", null=True, blank=True)
    Weight = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Vehicle Weight", blank=True, null=True)
    MaxCap = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Max Capicity", null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name="CountryName", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    pricerange = models.ForeignKey(PriceRange, verbose_name="Price Range", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    discount = models.ForeignKey(Discount, verbose_name="By Discount", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    othercategorie = models.ForeignKey(OtherCategorie, verbose_name="Other Categories", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    Description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description", null=True, blank=True)
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Vehicla Price", null=True, blank=True)
    TotalPrice = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Total Price", null=True, blank=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_cars():
        return Car.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_cars_by_CompanyId(company_id):
        if company_id:
            return Car.objects.filter(company=company_id)
        else:
            return Car.get_all_cars()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.CarName
```

Answer (score 0):

`searchresult` override when there are two or more query params, you must change your code like this to filter based on each query param:

```
searchresult = Car.objects.all()

if search:
    # searchresult = Car.objects.filter(Q(company__CompanyName__contains=companyname)|Q(CarName=carname)|Q(mdate__ManufacturingDate__contains=fromdate)|Q(mdate__ManufacturingDate__contains=todate)|Q(type__TypeName__contains=type)|Q(steering__SteeringName__contains=steering))
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(Q(company__CompanyName__contains=companyname)|Q(CarName=carname))

if companyname:
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(company__CompanyName=companyname)

if carname:
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(carname)

if fromdate:
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(mdate__ManufacturingDate=fromdate)

if todate:
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(mdate__ManufacturingDate=todate)

if type:
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(type__TypeName=type)

if steering:
    searchresult = searchresult.filter(steering__SteeringName=steering)
```

note: `type` is reserved python keyword change that.

Comment: ValueError at /searchdd
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
(I got this error)

Comment: Share your urls.py file

Comment: urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from app.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),    
    path('load-cars', views.load_cars, name='ajax_load_cars'),
    path('searchdd', views.searchdd, name='searchdd'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)